# matlab - deserialize a array

Tags: matlab, deserialization

I have a program that gathers data from a sensor, and saves it to a text file. the data n the text file looks like that:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
[9L,10L,11L,12L]
```

how do I de-serialize the arrays into vectors in matlab?

**note** I have some arrays with `float` values, so pleas refer to reading floats as well.

Comment: what's up with the 'L' on the 3rd row?

Comment: @GuntherStruyf it means it's of type `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not find any cleaner solution to this - the problem are of course the brackets at the beginning and end of every line. Here is a solution that reads the file line by line and runs `textscan` on strings with the brackets cut out. The individual vectors are stored in a `cell`:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
data = {};
while 1
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline); break; end
    A = textscan(tline, '%f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'Whitespace', '[ ]L\b\t');
    data{end+1} = A{1};
end
fclose(fid);
```

`L` is treated as delimiter here. If this information is really crucial for you and you want to perform a type cast to `uint64`, the above code will have to be modified.

**Edit** Following the comment of H.Muster, you could read the entire file in one go as follows:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
A = textscan(fid, '%f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'Whitespace', '[ ]L\b\t');
fclose(fid);
```

Now `A` contains a single column vector with all your data. So if you know the sizes of the vectors in every line, you can split `A` into correctly sized chunks. If not, and every vector can have a different size, you will have to go with the first solution.

Comment: Why don't you declare the brackets to whitespace: by adding `'whitespace', '[,]'` to the `textscan` options?

Comment: @H.Muster Good point. The problem remains however - a single call to `textscan` will read all the vectors into a single array. So I anyway have to do it in a loop... I have updated my answer.

Comment: @H.Muster Thank you, but you should have written your own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a small addition - once you remove the 'L' your data is valid matlab code. you could read it out as:

```
text_data = '[1,2,3,4]';
parsed_data = eval(text_data);
```